# Locomotive Scroll horizontal scrolling - Parallax elements are not in the correct position on document load

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am currently in the process of building an horizontal scroll website and I am using Locomotive Scroll as scrolling library.

The page is fairly simple: there are a few lines of text and some parallax images on the background.

Making the images move slower is is fairly simple and just involves assigning them two custom properties: data-scroll (identifies the component as a parallax elements) and data-scroll-speed="x" (defines its movement speed).

The images, however, do not appear to be in the correct position when the page loads. they are displayed much earlier than they should be and suddenly moved to their correct position when the user scrolls.

Only once the user has scrolled through the page the elements are moved to the correct position.

Neither Changing the position CSS property of the parallax elements from absolute to fixed or relative, nor changing their display value from block to inline-block seem to have any consequence.

I am fairly sure this is not an issue of the scroll library itself - there are several examples around the internet that show it working correctly (e.g. https://codepen.io/sfi0zy/pen/PoGvYyy ).

Here's a snippet that shows the issue I am encountering: https://codepen.io/rfBQ99vg/pen/QWddyRr

As you can see, the objects are only snapped to their position after the user has scrolled.

This is the code used to run the scroll - pretty straightforward, I do not believe the issue lies there:

```
const scroll = new LocomotiveScroll({
el: document.querySelector('[data-scroll-container]'),
smooth: true,
direction: "horizontal",
lerp:0.035,
multiplier:2.5
});
```

And these are the css properties of the parallax elements:

```
.flowers {
position:absolute;
background-size: cover;
background-position: center center;
}
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong, however, and I would greatly appreciate any feedback :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what was wrong: while Locomotive scroll accepts negative speed values (e.g. data-scroll-speed="-3" ) if the scroll direction is set to vertical, using them on a horizontal scrolling page results in the issue I described earlier. Unless I am mistaken, this is a limitation or a bug of the library in its current state.